# How to model this relation

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I am creating a messaging app where users have to be able to add contacts.
A contact is a pair of two users.

**First Question:**

I've got the following properties in my User class:

```
    Guid AccountId { get; set; }
    string Name { get; set; }

    List<Contact> Contacts { get; set; }
    List<Chat> Chats { get; set; }
```

Now I want to model the Contact class and this is what I came up with:

```
    Guid ContactId { get; set; }
    string Name { get; set; }

    User UserA { get; set; }
    User UserB { get; set; }
```

My issue with the Contact class is that every user has a list of contacts. Through this contact, it could be possible for one user to access the Contacts & Chats of another user.

Is this a valid concern? If so, how do I prevent this behaviour from happening?

**Second question:**

How could I name UserA & UserB in a more descriptive way? Using letters or numbers to count something feels dirty.

Answer (score 1):

You class Contacts create a circular reference problem , which I would discourage. 
The Contact class doesn't need to have the UserA and UserB properties. The Contact class would only be responsible to handle the Contact data:

1. AccountId
2. Name
3. LastName
4. NickName
5. IsBlackListed

In this scenario your second question is no relevant anymore and you have enforced responsabilities.

Comment: Then how do I fill the List<Contact> Contacts in User? I will have to query the database and determine whether or not a Contact belongs to the logged in user. How would you suggest I do that without storing the Contact owner?

Comment: See my edit. Use the AccountID to create a one to many relationship between the User and the Contact classes.